# Difference meanings with/without "only"

Tags: british-english

"If there is only a little bread on the table, keep yours in your hand." - Croatian proverb.

In Croatian language same proverb goes wihout "only". Why british english native translator have translated with "only"?

Comment: Another way of translating it would be *If there is little bread...*; neither means the same as *If there is a little bread...*.  This question needs to be expanded to explain what research you have done; it might also be better moved to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "only" is used here as an adverb to emphasize that the amount of bread is less than might be expected.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives/only):

> We use *only* as an adverb to mean that something is limited to some people, things, an amount or an activity:
>
> > ***Only*** a few hundred houses survived the hurricane without any damage.

Comment: Here, less than might prove necessary.